# Convert mysql DATETIME column to epoch seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, epoch

I have a column mysql `datetime` that is in DATETIME format.

Is there a way to `SELECT` this column in epoch seconds? If not, what would be the best way of converting the datetime format to epoch seconds? What type of field would be the best to capture this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function

Comment: Make sure your mysql server timezone is set correctly, otherwise you will get values you do not expect. EX: SET GLOBAL time_zone = UTC; and   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) * 1000 as epoc_ms. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html for more info.

Answer (score 28):

You can use :

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourfield) FROM yourtable;
```

And for UPDATE, the invers function is : FROM_UNIXTIME(...)