# How to get current date & time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Is there a value or command like DATETIME that I can use in a manual query to insert the current date and time?

```
INSERT INTO servers (
  server_name, online_status, exchange, disk_space, network_shares
) VALUES(
  'm1', 'ONLINE', 'ONLINE', '100GB', 'ONLINE' 'DATETIME' 
)
```

The quoted DATETIME value at the end is where I want to add the current date and time.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: NOW(), see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now ... And please, next time put at least some research effort into your question, this can be easily googled (therefore I just downvoted this question)

Comment: My question was more aimed at how I should use it in the syntax I posted above.

Comment: See franciscos answer for that. But this is very, very basic, it is just a function call. Therefore, again, you should put more research effort into the issue before posting a question and also you might want to read some instructions on SQL.

Comment: ironic. when putting effort into finding the answer you get to ... this answer!

Comment: forgot with this, long time not playing with database

Comment: @dirkk I agree with you about the research effort. But I think it's a valid question because if you would type `INSERT INTO sometable (\`datetime\`) VALUES ( NOW() ) ` in phpmyadmin's sql tab then phpmyadmin's hint would show an error icon with the message: `A comma or a closing bracket was expected near (`. This is confusing, because the sql query is valid but phpmyadmin says it's not.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You can use `NOW()`:

```
INSERT INTO servers (server_name, online_status, exchange, disk_space, network_shares, c_time)
VALUES('m1', 'ONLINE', 'exchange', 'disk_space', 'network_shares', NOW())
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'stamp' in 'field list' - Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just replace stamp with whatever your field name is, really. DOn't just copy and paste.

Comment: If it's a "date" field type, you can also use `curdate()`

Answer (score 35):

Use  **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()** or  **now()**

Like

```
INSERT INTO servers (server_name, online_status, exchange, disk_space,
network_shares,date_time) VALUES('m1','ONLINE','ONLINE','100GB','ONLINE',now() )
```

or

```
INSERT INTO servers (server_name, online_status, exchange, disk_space,
network_shares,date_time) VALUES('m1', 'ONLINE', 'ONLINE', '100GB', 'ONLINE'
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )
```

Replace date_time with the column name you want to use to insert the time.

Answer (score 30):

Even though there are many accepted answers, I think this way is also possible:

Create your **'servers'** table as following **:**

```
CREATE TABLE `servers`
(
      id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
      server_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      online_status varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      _exchange varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
      disk_space varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      network_shares varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      date_time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And your **INSERT** statement should be **:**

```
INSERT INTO servers (server_name, online_status, _exchange, disk_space, network_shares)
VALUES('m1', 'ONLINE', 'ONLINE', '100GB', 'ONLINE');
```

**My Environment:**

Core i3 Windows Laptop with 4GB RAM, and I did the above example on MySQL Workbench 6.2 (Version 6.2.5.0 Build 397 64 Bits)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` command.

See here: [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer is [SYSDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate).

```
INSERT INTO servers (
    server_name, online_status, exchange, disk_space,
    network_shares, date_time
)
VALUES (
    'm1', 'ONLINE', 'ONLINE', '100GB', 'ONLINE', SYSDATE()
);
```

We can change this behavior and make `NOW()` behave in the same way as `SYSDATE()` by setting [sysdate_is_now](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sysdate-is-now) command line argument to `True`.

Note that `NOW()` (which has `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` as an alias), differs from `SYSDATE()` in a **subtle** way:

> SYSDATE() returns the time at which it executes. This differs from the
> behavior for NOW(), which returns a constant time that indicates the
> time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored
> function or trigger, NOW() returns the time at which the function or
> triggering statement began to execute.)

As indicated by [Erandi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30149587/6862601), it is best to create your table with the `DEFAULT` clause so that the column gets populated automatically with the timestamp when you insert a new row:

```
date_time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATE()
```

---

If you want the current date in [epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10839151/6862601) format, then you can use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp). For example:

```
select now(3), sysdate(3), unix_timestamp();
```

would yield

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| now(3)                  | sysdate(3)              | unix_timestamp() |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| 2018-11-27 01:40:08.160 | 2018-11-27 01:40:08.160 |       1543282808 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Related:

- [Difference between NOW(), SYSDATE() & CURRENT_DATE() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24137752/6862601)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO servers (server_name, online_status, exchange, disk_space, network_shares)
VALUES('m1','ONLINE','exchange','disk_space','network_shares', NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

In database design, iIhighly recommend using Unixtime for consistency and indexing / search / comparison performance.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

One can always [convert to human readable](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php) formats afterwards, internationalizing as is individually most convenient.

```
FROM_ UNIXTIME (unix_timestamp, [format ])
```

Answer (score 1):

İf you make change default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it is more effiency,

```
ALTER TABLE servers MODIFY COLUMN network_shares datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use not only `now()`, also `current_timestamp()` and `localtimestamp()`. 
The main reason of incorrect display timestamp is inserting NOW() **with single quotes**! It didn't work for me in MySQL Workbench because of this IDE add single quotes for mysql functions and i didn't recognize it at once )

Don't use functions with single quotes like in MySQL Workbench. It doesn't work.

Answer (score -9):

```
$rs = $db->Insert('register',"'$fn','$ln','$email','$pass','$city','$mo','$fil'","'f_name','l_name=','email','password','city','contact','image'");
```

Comment: You should shortly explain your answer.

Comment: This answer means very little indeed!