# inserting current time and date in sql without creating data_time

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert data in sql but i want that the time to be the current date and to be inserted by itself in the date column.If yes,can u refer me somthing?

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing us some actual data, or something else, which would explain what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - insert current date/time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246309/mysql-insert-current-date-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `NOW()` MySQL function to insert the current date.

Here's an example, suppose you have a `date` column in your table that you want to store the current date in it:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(`col1`, col2, `current_date_col`)
VALUES ('data', 'another data', NOW())
```

This results in something like this:

```
col1  |  col1  |  current_date_col
______|________|____________________
      |        | 
data  |  data  |  2018-09-08 15:44:36
```