# how best to compare diff day hour minutes from string

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

i have field `diff_clock` and `diff_schedule`

i have set the *diff_clock* with these sql ( trigger )

```
CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time) / 3600 / 24), ' Days ',
            FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time), 3600 * 24 ) / 3600), ' Hours ',
            FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time), 3600) / 60), ' Minutes ',
            MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time), 60), ' Seconds '
        );
```

and for *diff_schedule* i only store **days, hours, and minutes**

so here the values ( **Varchar** ) :

diff_clock: `1 Days 11 Hours 45 Minutes 22 Seconds`

diff_schedule: `1 Days 2 Hours 43 minutes`

| id | diff_clock | diff_schedule | is_on_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 Days 11 Hours 45 Minutes 22 Seconds | 1 Days 2 Hours 43 minutes | how ? |

then how to compare **if the diff_clock > diff_schedule would print true** ?

full code the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER form_bu BEFORE UPDATE
ON form FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.clock_out_time IS NOT NULL  THEN
        SET NEW.diff_clock = CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time) / 3600 / 24), ' Days ',
            FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time), 3600 * 24 ) / 3600), ' Hours ',
            FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time), 3600) / 60), ' Minutes ',
            MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.clock_in_time, NEW.clock_out_time), 60), ' Seconds '
        );
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

its good choice to replace all string with empty string then convert or parse to integer then compare or anyone have conclusion ? should i store to other field that save the timeepoch ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839219/8122500

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourfield) FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Since those strings represent a duration, you need to convert them to formats that can be easily compared, either as strings or numbers. So if you convert them to a normalized format, e.g. "1 Days 11 Hours 45 Minutes 22 Seconds" would become "001 11:45:22", you could then use string comparison to determine which is greater. Another way would be to convert to an absolute number of seconds, and compare them as numbers. Either way, you have to do some string manipulation and/or some math to derive the resulting values to be compared.

Comment: Do backward. Store the values as second amount. Convert them to verbal representation with generated columns.